# Why are these lines tangent?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I was trying the problems at http://euclidthegame.org and for level 20, ending up using, but couldn't see the reason behind the following:

[image]

We have a circle centred on **B** and a point **A** outside the circle.
Construct **E** at the midpoint of **AB**.
Draw a circle centred on **E** passing through **A** and **B**.
**F** and **G** are the intersection points of the two circles.
Now the lines **AF** and **AG** are tangents to the original circle. How can we see that is the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $AB$ is the diameter of the 2nd circle, $\angle AGB=\frac{\pi}{2}$. 
This means that $AG \perp BG$ which is the radius of the 1st circle.

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to show that the line $(BG)\perp (AG)$. Notice that the triangles $AEG$ and $EBG$ are isosceles so

$$\angle{EAG}=\angle EGA$$ 
and 
$$\angle EGB=\angle EBG$$
so we have

$$\angle AGB=\angle AGE+\angle EGB=\frac12\angle AEB=\frac{180^°}{2}=90^°$$
hence the line $(AG)$ is tangent to the circle on $G$.